# How to parse nested JSON response in iOS app

Tags: ios, json

I have been trying to parse this JSON response in my iOS app. But unfortunately I am unable to do it. I have tried all the ways that can but still no luck. Can you please try to help me in this?

> "d_wtime" = "{'Sunday':{'fromhours':'12','fromtype':'PM','tohours':'12','totype':'AM','fromhours2':'12','fromtype2':'PM','tohours2':'12','totype2':'AM'},'Monday':{'fromhours':'12','fromtype':'PM','tohours':'12','totype':'AM','fromhours2':'12','fromtype2':'PM','tohours2':'12','totype2':'AM'},'Tuesday':{'fromhours':'12','fromtype':'PM','tohours':'12','totype':'AM','fromhours2':'12','fromtype2':'PM','tohours2':'12','totype2':'AM'},'Wednesday':{'fromhours':'12','fromtype':'PM','tohours':'12','totype':'AM','fromhours2':'12','fromtype2':'PM','tohours2':'12','totype2':'AM'},'Thursday':{'fromhours':'12','fromtype':'PM','tohours':'12','totype':'AM','fromhours2':'12','fromtype2':'PM','tohours2':'12','totype2':'AM'},'Friday':{'fromhours':'12','fromtype':'PM','tohours':'12','totype':'AM','fromhours2':'12','fromtype2':'PM','tohours2':'12','totype2':'AM'},'Saturday':{'fromhours':'12','fromtype':'PM','tohours':'12','totype':'AM','fromhours2':'12','fromtype2':'AM','tohours2':'12','totype2':'AM'}}";

Comment: Update your question with your attempt to parse this JSON and clearly explain what issues you are having.

Comment: With in the response that I have shown above..There are few tags. The output I need to show in the app is like beelow format                           Sunday         - 12 PM To 12 AM
Monday       - 12 PM To 12 AM
Tuesday        - 12 PM To 12 AM
Wednesday - 12 PM To 12 AM
Thursday      - 12 PM To 12 AM
Friday           - 12 PM To 12 AM
Saturday       - 12 PM To 12 AM
Sunday        - 12 PM To 12 AM

Comment: I need to use 4 tags out of the above response they are..."fromhours", "fromtype", "tohours", "totype"

Comment: There are countless tutorials and examples of parsing JSON in Swift or Objective-C. Try something. Then update your question with your code.

Comment: This is not valid JSON (strings must be in double quotes)

Answer (score 0):

should be something like

```
let JSONArray = response["d_wtime"] as! [[String:[String: String]]]
for JSONDic in JSONArray {
   let sundayJSON = JSONDic["Sunday"] as! [String: String]
   let fromHours = sundayJSON["fromhours"] as! String
   .
   .
   .
}
```

but i think that JSON is ugly you could have a more dynamic and generic JSON

Comment: Thank you so much for yor time. I need to work on thia actually. I realised from your comment that response is ugly. i will check our team members to get it nice and the proceed further on this.